# Button Dropdown for Bootstrap doesn't work

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

Read all the topics with the same problem and did everything that helped those in need, bat all of that doesn't work in my code( Please help.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta content="IE=edge" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible">
<meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" name="viewport">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Pacifico' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
</head>
<body>

<div class="main">
    <div class="container">

        <div class="row">
                <div class="btn-group">
                    <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg dropdown-toggle students" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">First <span class="caret"></span></button>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="#">sub first</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">sub second</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg teachers">Second</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>



<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/hover.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'm not seeing the problem?  https://jsfiddle.net/3jg552xL/

Comment: First button is a drop-down button for me. In which browser are you testing?

Comment: Did you try adding `https:` for jQuery script?

Comment: Yes, Chitrang, I only needed to add `https:`. (why don't you add answer instead of comment??)

Answer (score 0):

You have not included the class `dropdown`. You need to include the dropdown button and the menu under this class and it will work.